# PowerShell variable definition from a pscustomobject

Tags: powershell

i've got this piece of code from a script i found on the web (just showing the part that interests me)

```
ForEach  ($Computer in  $Computername) {
    $adsi  = [ADSI]"WinNT://$Computername"
    $adsi.Children | where {$_.SchemaClassName -eq  'user'} |  ForEach {
        [pscustomobject]@{
        UserName = $_.Name[0]
        SID = ConvertTo-SID -BinarySID $_.ObjectSID[0]
        PasswordAge = [math]::Round($_.PasswordAge[0]/86400)
        LastLogin = If ($_.LastLogin[0] -is [datetime]){$_.LastLogin[0]}Else{'Never logged  on'}
        UserFlags = Convert-UserFlag  -UserFlag $_.UserFlags[0]
        MinPasswordLength = $_.MinPasswordLength[0]
        MinPasswordAge = [math]::Round($_.MinPasswordAge[0]/86400)
        MaxPasswordAge = [math]::Round($_.MaxPasswordAge[0]/86400)
        BadPasswordAttempts = $_.BadPasswordAttempts[0]
        MaxBadPasswords = $_.MaxBadPasswordsAllowed[0]
        }
    }
}
```

the code displays things on the console, but i would like to define/use these values as variables instead (as i want to use them in a hash table afterwards to send them in a http/POST request afterwards)

is there a way to get all these attributes as variables such as $LastLogin, $MinPasswordAge etc ?

as i don't want to display them, but send them in a POST  like this :

```
$postParams = @{LastLogin=$LastLogin;MinPasswordAge=$MinPasswordAge}
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://example.com/foobar -Method POST -Body $postParams
```

to be honest i'm a complete newbie in PowerShell (i'm a Perl guru) and i don't know what pscustomobject does in there, i just want to define the variables in that loop, and use them at the end.

i've tried a couple of things with no success (can post them if required)
thanks !

Comment: nm, i found the solution (just got rid of that pscustomobject hash completely, and assigning the variables directory, i will remove my post or mark it as resolved

Answer (score -1, accepted):

nm, 
i found the solution a minute ago.

just got rid of that pscustomobject hash completely, and assigning the variables directory

```
    $adsi.Children | where {$_.SchemaClassName -eq  'user'} |  ForEach {

        $UserName = $_.Name[0]
        $SID = ConvertTo-SID -BinarySID $_.ObjectSID[0]
        $PasswordAge = [math]::Round($_.PasswordAge[0]/86400)
        $LastLogin = If ($_.LastLogin[0] -is [datetime]){$_.LastLogin[0]}Else{'Never logged  on'}
        $UserFlags = Convert-UserFlag  -UserFlag $_.UserFlags[0]
        $MinPasswordLength = $_.MinPasswordLength[0]
        $MinPasswordAge = [math]::Round($_.MinPasswordAge[0]/86400)
        $MaxPasswordAge = [math]::Round($_.MaxPasswordAge[0]/86400)
        $BadPasswordAttempts = $_.BadPasswordAttempts[0]
        $MaxBadPasswords = $_.MaxBadPasswordsAllowed[0]

        Write-Host $UserName

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your [own solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58998250/45375) works, but only if you perform all processing inside the `ForEach-Object` script block (unless there's only ever 1 iteration, which doesn't appear to be the case here).

If you want to process the results later, you can simply collect them in an array by assigning the entire `foreach` loop to a variable (code shortened):

```
$allUsers = foreach ($Computer in  $Computername) {
    $adsi  = [ADSI]"WinNT://$Computername"
    $adsi.Children | where {$_.SchemaClassName -eq  'user'} |  ForEach {
        # Output a custom object for each user.
        [pscustomobject]@{
          ComputerName = $Computer  # also record the computer name
          UserName = $_.Name[0]
          SID = ConvertTo-SID -BinarySID $_.ObjectSID[0]
          # ...
        }
    }
}
```

You can then simply enumerate the collected `[pscustomobject]`s and access their *properties* rather than using variables:

```
foreach ($user in $allUsers) {
   # Use the properties to define a hashtable for later use in a http/POST request.
   $ht = @{
     User = $user.UserName
     # ...
   }
}
```